# How to send API response through express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, localhost

Im currently trying to pass the JSON result from my newsapi.org call. I cannot however figure out how to do it? Any help would be great!! Thanks

```js
newsapi.v2.topHeadlines({
  category: 'general',
  language: 'en',
  country: 'au'
}).then(response => {
  //console.log(response);
  const respo = response;
});

app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.send(respo);
});
```

Comment: what is the error you are receiving? did you start your node server? what port is it running on? what happens when you type `localhost:<port number>` into your browser?

Comment: What are you getting when you are visiting at the `index route: /`. You must be getting an error that `TypeError: respo is not defined`. that newsapi call must be inside the `app.get("/")` call as this is asynchronous. 

Your question is incomplete, make sure you provide us a minimum reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to call the API in each new request, then you would put it inside the request handler:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    newsapi.v2.topHeadlines({
      category: 'general',
      language: 'en',
      country: 'au'
    }).then(response => {
      //console.log(response);
      res.send(response);
    }).catch(err => {
      res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

If you wish to call the API every once in awhile and cache the result, then you would do something like this:

```
let headline = "Headlines not yet retrieved";

function updateHeadline() {

    newsapi.v2.topHeadlines({
      category: 'general',
      language: 'en',
      country: 'au'
    }).then(response => {
      headline = response;
    }).catch(err => {
      headline = "Error retrieving headlines."
      // need to do something else here on server startup
    });
}
// get initial headline
updateHeadline();

// update the cached headline every 10 minutes
setInterval(updateHeadline, 1000 * 60 * 10);



app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.send(headline);
});
```